# Looking for an app to help me schedule based on availability

Tags: webapp-rec

I have to create a rehearsal schedule for a play and I'm wondering if there's a web app that would help me quickly determine when different combinations of people are all free.

I have seen Doodle, but I don't think it will work, because I would be having to input the schedules myself because most of the people aren't spending a lot of time online. And without the pro version I'd need to make an account or each of them, right?

Google Calendar has some ability to do this if I make a whole bunch of calendars for everyone.

Is there something a little quicker/more streamlined?

Answer (score 0):

I would try a few of the sites mentioned in this article of [Alternatives to Google Calendar](http://news.cnet.com/8301-17939_109-10255636-2.html).

My sense is Google Calendar is the best option because it is free, accessible from mobile devices, web, etc., and like you mentioned it puts the responsibility on the individual to maintain their own calendar.

Comment: i don't have people's calendars for this... i am putting in everything myself. I'm going to see if I can check availability of various people if I put them all in as separate calendars on my own account.

Comment: Oh I see.  I think most online apps will require you to have different accounts to manage different calendars, unfortunately.  Another thought with Google Calendar is to set yourself as a delegate:  http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=117596  You can then give everyone the opportunity to manage their own schedule, but you would also have control to add events on their behalf.  With individual accounts, you'd definitely be able to schedule events normally.  You could even accept them on their behalf.